# Отследить изменение адресной книги ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

нашел метод

```
NSError err;
ABAddressBook iOSAddressBook = ABAddressBook.Create(out err);
iOSAddressBook.ExternalChange += (object sender, ExternalChangeEventArgs e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("qorkkkk");
};
```

но он не работает

Comment: Ну, судя по логике, вы создаете новую адресную книгу. Вам нужно получить существующую.

Comment: мне нужен какой то обсервер.  чтоб когда пользователь добавлял или изменял какой то контакт то срабатывало событие